# nginx on docker exits immediately

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, nginx

Short story long: I have a little project here that needs static website serving. So I set up an nginx docker container on main dev machine (XUbuntu). Working **fine** when created with

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -v /someprojectpath:/usr/var/nginx/html:ro --name myweb nginx
```

Then I had a spare Raspberry Pi and figured "hm, why not pull up a notch and run that container on the pi?" Said and done: Installed docker client on the pi through

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

I then created a folder on the pi (original Raspberry Pi 2B with 8GB SD-Card, up-to-date Raspbian) in /home/pi/www and put that in above mentioned command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v /home/pi/www:/usr/var/nginx/html:ro --name myweb nginx
```

But this time, the container just exits after a few seconds without serving.

I searched a bit and found some remarks about "daemon:off" but when I checked the container, it is already running with "daemon:off" (or at least it *should* - no idea how to verify that).

**Why is the behavior different? And how do I fix the early exit?**

### Update

Just for fun, I tried `docker run hello-world`. *It did not give any output!*
I inspected both images (hello-world and nginx) and confirmed `"Architecture" = arm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

On a Raspberry Pi **2** , you need explicitly images for ARM **v6**.

So I came across `arm32v6/nginx` which resulted in a `missing manifest` error.

Next step was to opt for an explicit version, for example `arm32v6/ngninx:stable-alpine`.

And that finally did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Append this at the end of your docker run command:

```
-g 'daemon off;'
```

It should be in this syntax not "daemon:off" as you mentioned.

Hope that helps

Comment: Didn't help. I didn't expect it to do, though. There must be something else,  I am missing. The syntax from question is from docker inspect.